# longest ungolfable quine

Tags: quine

Create a quine that cannot be golfed. Your score is your byte count, where higher is better. If someone finds a shorter version, their score is your original byte count, and you lose points

Scoring example:

original submission, 34 bytes // score is 34

```
function(this){self.printquine();}
```

golfed, 31 bytes              // score is 34, original submission is scored 31

```
function(this){_.printquine();}
```

golfed again by someone else, 18 bytes // score is 31, first golfed submission is scored 18

```
this.printquine();
```

Here "golfing" is defined as creating a shorter version of **someone else's** source file exclusively by removing characters or rearranging existing characters (without affecting its quine-ness). This seems like a good way to define it because otherwise googling the shortest quine in a given language would be the only reasonable starting point.

Standard loopholes apply, unless you have a creative use of one then go for it. 
Use this site's definition of a valid [quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine), if you can actually find one that's agreed on.

Comment: Could someone that thinks this is unclear please say what they think is unclear?

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I voted this as unclear for two reasons -- the first is regarding "chain" scoring. Say that A scores 100, but then B comes and golfs it down to 95, thus B scores 100. Then C comes along and golfs it further down to 90. Does C score 95 or 100? /// The second is the second-to-last sentence. Opening up standard loopholes is almost always a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Those seem like bad choices rather than sources of unclarity.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork valid point i'll clarify the scoring.

Comment: Now your first golf (swapping `self` for `_`) is invalid according to your definition of golfing (`exclusively by removing characters or rearranging existing characters`).

Comment: ノ( º _ ºノ) yeet do you have a constructive suggestion? @AdmBorkBork

Comment: Well, it looks like you're contradicting yourself by saying that changing `self` to `_` is valid but also saying that it's not valid. I suggest editing this question to clarify whether golfs like this one are valid or not.

Comment: Also, do I understand it right, should someone's else quine display MY source code, or his?

Comment: this might be better as a [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenge, but with no "safe" time frame? This is why we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges): to improve challenges so they don't get downvoted / closed.

Comment: I'm actually voting to close as off-topic, because: `Standard loopholes apply, unless you have a creative use of one then go for it`, which means that there are basically no rules, and this thus has no objective winning criterion. I think the core of the challenge is an interesting play on the "golf" idea and the scoring has potential, but it needs refinement before it fits our standards.

Comment: Use Malbolge! Nobody will ever want to golf a quine program in this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B), 1 byte

I guess I'm not winning any points for creativity.

```
Q
```

Comment: I don't think this fits our standard rules of what makes a quine, as outlined in the bottom paragraph of the challenge.

Comment: ok but [HQ9+], 0 bytes
checkmate

Comment: @KennethTaylor my quine is longer, therefore I still win

Comment: That's not how the scoring works...